# Virtual machine - DNS hostname problems on Windows Server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, hostname, vmware-workstation, dynamic-dns

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 in a local domain with an local DNS server running. My clients are configured to use this DNS server.

Today, I had the problem with a client that could not log in due to network issues. I did an nslookup at the server host-name and I got 3 IP addresses back, it should be only one.

Later I discovered that the other IP addresses belong to VMWare Network adapters. If I delete the DNS entries in the panel they come back after 10-15 minutes. At the moment I disabled the network adapters for a quick fix but it is planned to run some services in virtual machines soon.

**So my question is**:

How do I configure the server that the hostname "company-server" is only linked to the server IP address?

Currently, the other interfaces get the server hostname too.

I could not find any issues like that on sf or Google.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows DNS server will listen on and register DNS records for every network adapter that is bound to the DNS server. The fix is to unbind the VMware network adapters in the DNS Server management console. You should also configure the VMware network adapters to not register in DNS in the Advanced properties of the IPv4 of each of those network adapters.